# matplotlib secondary axes that spans half of the first one

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I need a plot with two y axis but the second one should be half of the first one.

I was thinking on two different plot overlapped but I guess there is a simpler way.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check matplotlib gallery.
Maybe you are looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3MSr.png) or [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/two_scales.html).

Then if you want ax2 (right axis) to span half of ax1 (left axis), get the y-limits of ax1:

```
(min_y, max_y) = ax1.get_ylim()
```

and set ax2 limits accordingly. For example:

```
ax2.set_ylim((min_y, max_y / 2.))
```

**Edit:**

After your comments, I worked a solution that probably fits better your needs. Here is the code modified from mpl gallery:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color='b')

for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color='r')

(min_y, max_y) = ax2.get_ylim()
dist = (max_y - min_y) * 2.

ax2.set_ylim((min_y, max_y + dist))

yticklabels = ax2.get_yticklabels()
yticks = ax2.get_yticklines()

nlabels = len(yticklabels) / 2
nticks = len(yticks) / 2

for i in range(len(yticklabels)):
    if i < nlabels:
        yticklabels[i].set_color('r')
    else:
        yticklabels[i].set_visible(False)

for i in range(len(yticks)):
    if i < nticks:
        yticks[i].set_color('r')
    else:
        yticks[i].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you so much.  
Actually it was not so easy as I thought...